# How can I open a console to interact with Express app?

Tags: node.js, express

How can I open a console to interact with my Express app?

I am trying to test whether some methods work to create a model. I'm using SequelizeJS, but that shouldn't matter for the answer to this question.

I am used to Rails where I can do `$ heroku run rails console` then interact with the models in my app. I would like to do the same in Express.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Make your app export the express instance (`module.exports = app`)
- Run `node`, which will put you in a REPL loop
- Require your project: `var myApp = require('./app')`

Comment: Using REPL is a direct answer to what OP is asking, however it's not really the standard solution for the *problem* OP is having. Setting up tests, as pointed out by beautifulcoder is the correct solution.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer -- OP is asking how to interact with the express app.  Tests are great, _if you know what you're doing_.  If you're in the process of figuring it out, a REPL loop where you can inspect elements is needed.  I perceived the OP's question as asking for the latter.  Once you figure it out, you write tests :)

Comment: Using REPL has it's own set of complexity, and it doesn't always map 1 to 1 to the actual target environment. ( think of the _ operator ), directly typing commands into REPL requires you to basically never make a typo if you are writing more then 1 line of code and you will lose all your calls and state if you close the session. Never mind the added complexity when introducing stubs or other testing related concepts.
Unless OP is a robot you are setting him up on a path of pain by recommending REPL as a good way to test your app.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer - REPL is a tool, like anything else.  I don't know exactly what the OP needs, and _neither do you_.  Typing `app.method()` and _seeing the result_ is easier than writing unit tests and if you're not that familiar with express, a _lot_ more useful.

Comment: Unless you completely separate your express interface from your implementation ( I have 5$ right here OP didn't do that ), you can not just just call `app.method` because the methods expect express specific http arguments (and that on it's own is already assuming the methods are not declared inline using 'app.get() / post()' ). There are standard, widely used solution for that, testing is one of them. REPL definitely is not, you would need to manually construct an HTTP call in order to test the individual methods, or stub the arguments ( inside REPL ) , which is a a lot typing.

Comment: omfg, it's a tool.  I'll re-iterate _you don't know what the OP has or needs_.  If it doesn't work for him/her, fine.  But _you are not the person to answer that_.  Your arrogance in assuming you are is absurd.

Comment: I am not sure why you are thinking there would be confusion about what OP wants. OP has a specific, pretty well know problem, there is a specific pretty well know solution for it, and it's not REPL.

Comment: _you don't know exactly what the OP needs_.  Can I say that clearer?  Just go away, this conversation is pointless.

Comment: I am not sure why you are thinking this conversation is pointless. We are examining facts and exchanging arguments to determine the best solution for OP. All tough you haven't brought up much points about the benefits of REPL for the problem OP is having, please do. Or if you are in fact uncertain about what that problem exactly is, please share what questions you have. I am listing, or post a comment on the question if you want to address OP directly.

Comment: Here's my issue - I don't disagree with you that your solution is valid. I disagree that you're making some blanket statement that a REPL is always useless. You don't know the OP's structure, you don't know what he/she is trying to accomplish. The only thing said was "I want to see if some methods work". You don't know if those are bound to an HTTP request, you don't know _anything at all about what the OP has_. You're making assumptions _based on the way you do thing_ that have absolutely no basis in anything. Until the OP provides more information, your opinion is biased & this is pointless.

Comment: I don't think I said REPL is always useless, it's just not very useful for testing. OP is saying `interacting with express app`  and `testing some methods`, I find that to be enough to determine testing is what he needs.  It's a clear testing problem, he needs to research testing to solve the problem, not REPL.

Comment: You really don't get it do you?  Until OP actually responds to something _this conversation is pointless_

Comment: Ah, I actually felt like my last comment ( and your previous one ) cleared things up a bit. I'm sorry you feel that way.

Comment: It is impossible to clear anything up.  This conversation has about as much merit as discussing what type of tires are best for a car when you know _nothing_ about the rest of the car other than that the owner said "I want more traction".

Comment: I would love to go into a deep ( and honest ) discussion where I deconstruct your analogy and point out which point of it make sense and which points don't, but, I think that might actually be pointless. I might have been spending to much time on reddit.

Comment: You realize that's not the point of analogies, right?  To be 100% accurate?  Look, if OP actually responds I'll be happy to continue this, but until then (as I've been trying to say for a while now), this is just noise.

Comment: You misinterpreted me again !  
I am not saying the analogy needs to be 100% accurate, it just needs to make sense. And to be fair there are some valid parts to this particular analogy, hence the deconstructing part, I do not want to just negate it in full. I agree this is noise, I will stop the discussion here.

Comment: @zyklus - thanks a lot for the answer, seems to be what I'm looking for, will have a chance to try it out in a bit

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer - I appreciate where you are coming from with suggesting a testing framework (I've done plenty of testing / TDD).  For people looking to test their app - this is definitely the right solution. In this case I'm really just looking for the "console" equivalent to what I had experienced in other frameworks :)

Comment: Cool, I am happy you found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but see Node 8 has added more debugging capabilities:
 * https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Answer (score -1):

You could use browserify to pass your back end methods and functions into the web application/client side browser. It will run just like you would use your code from within node.js.

So, as you would require a node module into your back-end node application, you may browserify a node module into your front-end web application.

For more details, see link here: (http://browserify.org/)

```
/*In node, you use module like this*/
var thingToCall = require('/moduleInNode');
/*Whereas you would do similarly using browserify*/
```

For a more detailed explanation of how to do so I would refer to this page(https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/cross-platform-javascript/) and 
read beginning with the section titled "CommonJS Modules Primer."

Answer (score -3):

If you want to test your individual methods from your app the best thing to do really is to set up a test framework as mentioned by beautifulcoder.
This really is the easiest and most robust way to run separated parts of logic in your application.
You do not have to start writing tests immediately, but that would be a good logical next step.
This is a lot more convenient then using the REPL if you want to run certain methods multiple times, introduce stubs etc...

I can recommend using a mocha/sinon/chai/supertest setup for testing, all tough you should know there are much more testing frameworks out there so a bit of research might be in order. It's all subjective in the end.