# Access to Express.js and Prisma console

Tags: shell, express, prisma

So im building app based on Express and using Prisma ORM. What i need is to SSH to a server, open up express.js console and create new db entry using prisma. Something similar to `python manage.py shell` for Django or `rails console` for Rails. Is there a solution for this of any kind?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292438/how-can-i-open-a-console-to-interact-with-express-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I pointed in the comment there is a way ( kind of ) to get access to a running express instance. If that's all you need follow:

[How can I open a console to interact with Express app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292438/how-can-i-open-a-console-to-interact-with-express-app)

Express doesn't exactly have a feature like `rails console` which is a framework feature in that case.

That said,  I question the long term implication of this approach. If you really just need to seed some data, write an "init" script, and call it after you ssh into a server or using some CI/CD approach. This is more re-usable, since you can even pass a json file to the script to load dynamic data.

Also, Prismajs has an official way to seed the data ( if that's what you need) that you can leverage:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/seed-database

UPDATE:

If you are able to run to code on your machine and point the remote database, then you can use `node --inspect` to debug in a chrome console. Which should give you about the same effect as a rails REPL

https://medium.com/@tbernardes/debugging-nodejs-with-chrome-inspector-devtools-1cd2ef323b5e

Comment: Well i need to read some data and then write some data. So it's not ideal to seed or to write script. I guess it can't be helped then. Thanks

Comment: I am likely missing some context here. But can you not read the data you need from the database in a script and then act on it? 

Express is just a http server. You can fully drive prisma ORM from a script.

Comment: I need realtime interactivity. For example i'm querying for some data and act based on that data, so i don't need to write complex checks and logic and then just observe results. The option where i rerun script every time i made some adjustments is a pain

Comment: It's kind of a tricky situation then.  Assuming you are SSH-ing to the server to interact with the actual database, there might be another option.  You could run the codebase locally, and point it to your production database. Then you can use node — inspect to get a REPL console in a browser console to interact with the code

Comment: thanks for update. i'll definitely give it a try